# For comprehension with Partial function

Tags: scala

```
def testDef ={
val strMap =  scala.collection.mutable.Map[Int,String]()
strMap.map{
  case (k,v) => for{
    d <- MyDAO.findById(k) //d is an Entity of some Type T. findById returns Option[T]
    field <- extract(d.address) //field is a String 
   } yield field 
 }
}
```

My understanding is that when using `for` comprehension first generator type is what determines type of `yield` ing result. e.g. in above case `d` is of of some type `T` thought that must have been required to `yield` from `for` comprehension.

Particular above usage of `for` comprehension (with `case` ) works fine but I am confused because I am able to `yield` any type of "things". e.g. thought since first generator is of some type `T` that's the only thing I can `yield` but I am able to `yield` `field` too, which is of type `String`. And not only able to `yield` `String` but anything e.g. for the sake of this example following works as well.

```
case class Person

def test(person:Person) ={
val strMap =  scala.collection.mutable.Map[Int,String]()
strMap.map{
  case (k,v) => for{
    d <- MyDAO.findById(k) //d is an Entity of some Type T. findById returns Option[T]
    field <- extract(d.address) //field is a String 
   } yield person 
 }
}
```

I understand `for` desugars to `map` but why would above work?

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand your question. Can you please edit it?

Comment: What does `findById` return? I imagine it is `Option[T]`, so in that case you are doing something like `MyDAO.findById(k).map(extract(_.address))` in the inner `for` comprehension which returns an `Option[String]`.

Comment: @goral edited question. hope it's clear now

Comment: @Lee : please see updates

Answer (score 4):

For comprehensions have to work on compatible *monads*, not type parameters.

```
for (x <- xs; y <- ys(x)) yield f(y)
```

desugars to

```
xs.flatMap{ x => ys(x).map(f(y)) }
```

so `xs` had better have a `flatMap` that can take whatever `ys(x).map(f(y))` spits out.

Generally, a `flatMap` signature on a class `M[A]` will look like `flatMap[B](f: A => M[B]): M[B]`.  So, as long as the outer and inner containers are the same type (e.g. both `Option`), everyone's happy.  The type being stored (first `A`, then `B`) doesn't matter at all, unless the container `M` can only take some types and you try to make it hold something it can't.

Also, if the inner container can be coerced into the form of the outer, everyone's also happy (e.g. there is an implicit to convert `Option` into a `Seq`, so you can do stuff like `List("fish", null).flatMap(x => Option(x))`.

If you try something where the containers are different shapes, it won't work.  For instance:

```
for (x <- Option("fish"); y <- List(x,x)) yield y
```

complains that an `Option` is required.

Comment: Unless you change it to `for (x <- Option("fish").toIterable; y <- List(x,x)) yield y`

Comment: @sourcedelica - Right, because then the Option isn't an option any longer; it's an `Iterable` which is the right shape (superclass of `List`).

Comment: Yep - you can sometimes coerce the outer container to be compatible with the inner. Generally `Option` and `Iterable` can be coerced into playing well with each other.  (Sounds like my kids).